# How do I get the category filter to work with Xpages cloud tag

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, tag-cloud

I have set up a tagcloud from the extension library in Xpages. But what I cannot get to work is when the user clicks on a cloud tag entry, they go to the categorized view but it doesn't position to that category or subset to only that category.

I checked the Xpages Extension Library demo and can't figure out how it is supposed to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Bryan

Comment: Some code would be greatly appreciated. Can you please provide your tag cloud object, the code that runs on click, and how your view is set up on the target XPage?

Comment: Is it possible to specify a separate db for the tag cloud control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can show all entries from view for a clicked tag:

(1) Create a categorized view in which the tags you want to show are in first categorized column. Add in following columns the values you want to show for a tag.

(2) Put in `dominoViewCloudData` this view name, the XPage which has to be called when a tag is selected and the parameter name for url where the selected tag will be provided

```xml
    <xe:dominoViewCloudData
        ...
        viewName="yourViewName"
        linkTargetPage="/TagViewEntryList.xsp"
        linkRequestParam="tag">
    </xe:dominoViewCloudData>
```

(3) Create the target XPage with a view control and set the categoryFilter to selected tag. You can read the tag from url with `param['tag']`. If your tag can contain space characters then you have to replace the "+" from url back to space with `replace()`

```xml
    <xp:viewPanel
        ...
        <xp:this.data>
            <xp:dominoView
                var="view1"
                viewName="yourViewName">
                    <xp:this.categoryFilter><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                        var tag = param['tag']; 
                        if(tag) { 
                            return tag.replace("+", " ");
                        } return null}]]>
                    </xp:this.categoryFilter>
            </xp:dominoView>
        </xp:this.data>
        <xp:viewColumn
            ...
        </xp:viewColumn>
    </xp:viewPanel>
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify a separate database for the tag cloud?

Comment: @pipalia: I couldn't find a way to specify a database for tag cloud view yet, unfortunately.